# Is the "line-height" style safe to use?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I wonder if the **line-height** style attribute is safe to use in terms of layout and design?

I have a problem where text lines have smaller space between them in IE6 and IE7, but works fine in all other major browsers.

So I added `line-height:20px;` and now it looks good in IE6 and 7 also, but the funny thing is that the line-height didn't change in Chrome or Firefox, or Opera or Safari!

Anybody know why it didn't change?

Here is the code:

```
<font color="#000000" face="Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif" style="font-size:13px; font-weight:bold; line-height:20px;">
```

Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with the FONT element? Is this HTML5?

Comment: @Sime Vidas, it's an element deprecated in, or as of, html 4, as I recall; ref: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element).

Comment: @David Yea, I was being sarcastic :) @Camran It is possible that ancient elements (like FONT) have quirks in older browsers. Switching to modern markup may very well solve your issue.

Comment: @Sime, I *was* quite surprised that you didn't know of it. What can I say? It's been a *long* day, I must be tired... =D

Comment: oh, come on, it's beautiful, it even mixes css and the font tag to set styles. It defines a transitional moment on the history of markup. Trust me, one day you will look at this and get teary-eyed.  A Museum piece. +1 to Camran for posting it, +1 to stevelove for the current way to go about it.

Comment: @Sebastian / Sime: +1 for sarcasm!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question, line-height is pretty safe. However, `<font>` is not. It was deprecated in HTML 4.01 and is dropped from HTML5. You should use CSS for font colors and font family. The reason it didn't appear to change in the other browsers you mention might have something to do with `<font>` being a presentational tag and not structural, but that's just a guess.

CSS:

```
.specialText {
    color:#000;
    font:bold 13px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    line-height:20px;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="specialText">My special text</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `<font>` tag anymore because it's not supported in HTML5. Your best option is to use embedded/external CSS. Here's an example:

HTML

```
<span class="example">Your text here</span>
```

CSS

```
.example{
line-height:20px;
color:#000;//#000000 is the same thing
font:bold 13px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```